# Python search a line containing some string above a particular line and update its value

Tags: python, pam

The below code works if I try to insert a new pam rule

`auth    [default=ignore success=1]  pam_succeed_if.so user in user1:user2`

just above the line of an existing **pam_lastlog** rule in the **/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac** file

`account       required     pam_lastlog.so inactive=10`

```
found = False
users="user1 user2"
for line in fileinput.FileInput("/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac", inplace=1):
    obj = re.match(r"^(?!#).*auth.*pam_succeed_if.so\s+user\s+in\s+.*\n", line)
    if obj:
        found = True
        line = re.sub(r'user\s+in\s+[\w:]+',"user in %s" % ":".join(users.split()), obj.group(0))
    sys.stdout.write(line)
    fileinput.close()
if not found:
    pam_rule = "auth    [default=ignore success=1]  pam_succeed_if.so user in %s\n" %":".join(users.split())
    for line in fileinput.input("/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac", inplace=True):
        if re.search(r"pam_lastlog.so\s+.*inactive=", line):
            sys.stdout.write(pam_rule)
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

If this **pam_succeed_if** rule (which is inserted by above code) is already present in that pam file but at two places, one is above **pam_lastlog.so** line and another one is above the **pam_faillock.so** rule line with different user(s), then I have to update only the users part of the **pam_succeed_if** rule which is just above the **pam_lastlog.so** rule only and not the one which is above **pam_faillock.so**

Comment: Please simplify the description. Reading 5-line-phrase containing few different filenames is pretty hard.

Answer (score 0):

For solution, I have used multiple line search using regular expression

```
found = False
users="user1 user2"
lines = open("/etc/pam.d/system-auth").readlines()
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    succobj = re.match(r"^(?!#).*auth.*pam_succeed_if.so\s+user\s+in\s+.*\n", line)
    if succobj:
        lastlogobj = re.match(r"^.*pam_lastlog.so\s+.*inactive=.*\n", lines[i+1])
        if lastlogobj:
            found = True
            lines[i] = re.sub(r'user\s+in\s+[\w:]+',"user in %s" % ":".join(users.split()), succobj.group(0))
if found:
    open("/etc/pam.d/system-auth","w").writelines(lines)
else:
    pam_rule = "auth    [default=ignore success=1]  pam_succeed_if.so user in %s\n" %":".users.split())
    for line in fileinput.input("/etc/pam.d/system-auth", inplace=True):
        if re.search(r"pam_lastlog.so\s+.*inactive=", line):
            sys.stdout.write(pam_rule)
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

If there is any other possible sophisticated method please let me know